# Binaries from first stage aren't picked up in second stage (Docker multi-stage builds)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

There is an image, `confluentinc/ksqldb-cli`, I want to augment with a library (https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime).

Since this image `confluentinc/ksqldb-cli` is very bare, it doesn't contain any package managers like `apt` or `apt`.

So, my idea is to use Docker multi-stage builds.

The first builds the library `libfaketime` using the `alpine` image.

The second stage copies that library to the `confluentinc/ksqldb-cli` image.

Before building the library, I wanted to test if I can at least do the same with `git`:

```
FROM alpine:3.17.2

RUN apk update && apk add git

FROM confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.28.2

COPY --from=0 /usr/bin/git /bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Once I enter the container and type in: `git`, I get:

```bash
/usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

I can see `git` in `/bin`, however. Even if I `cd /bin` and `./git`, I still get:

```bash
bash: ./git: No such file or directory
```

How can I copy binaries from one stage to another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ksqldb image is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (Fedora) which uses the `dnf` package manager. You can use that to install git like this:

```
FROM confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.28.2
USER root
RUN dnf install -y git
USER appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

The image is set to run under the 'appuser' user, so you have to switch to root and back when installing packages.

Installing using a package manager is much preferred over copying binaries. You can't just copy a binary, since it probably depends on a number of libraries that you also need to copy. Those libraries might again depend on other libraries that are included with the OS. Mixing libraries from Alpine with libraries from Red Hat is most likely not going to work.

Comment: Ah, thanks! How did you know which distro it was based on? Is there an easy way to tell?

Comment: Also, if I was building something a bit larger, and I wanted to make use of multi-stage builds to reduce the final size, would it be OK to copy binaries if the distro is the same?

Comment: `/etc/os-release` can often show you the base version. And yes, you should safely be able to copy binaries in a multi-stage Dockerfile, as long as the base is the same. Remember that you might need to copy dependencies as well.